# Web scraping using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from yellow pages, website being [this](https://www.yellowpages.com.au/find/boat-yacht-sales/melbourne-vic)

I want this `div class= search-results listing-group`

I tried this

```
parent = soup.find('div',{'class':"search-results listing-group"})
```

But, I am not getting any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This URL has anti-scraping protections in place, which resist programmatic HTML extraction.  That's the main reason why you're not getting any output.  You can see this by examining the raw data returned from a request:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://www.yellowpages.com.au/find/boat-yacht-sales/melbourne-vic"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)

print(soup)
```

Excerpt:

> This page appears when online data protection services detect requests coming from your computer network which appear to be in violation of our website's terms of use.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using requests?
It appears the webpage does not allow automated scraping, atleast using Beautiful Soup. 
I tried scraping it for you and this is what I see in the content.

```html
<p style="font-weight: bold;">Why did this happen?</p>
 <p style="margin-top: 20px;">This page appears when online data protection services detect requests coming from your computer network which appear to be in violation of our website's terms of use.</p>
 </div>, <div style="border-bottom: 1px #E7E7E7 solid;
                                 margin-top: 20px;
                                 margin-bottom: 20px;
                                 height: 1px;
                                 width: 100%;">
 </div>, <div style="margin-left: auto;
                                 margin-right: auto;
                                 font-size: 20px;
                                 max-width: 460px;
                                 text-align: center;">
                         We value the quality of content provided to our customers, and to maintain this, we would like to ensure real humans are accessing our information.</div>, <div style="margin-left: auto;
                                 margin-right: auto;
                                 margin-top: 30px;
                                 max-width: 305px;">
```

You might have to try other (legitimate) methods of scraping it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the page you are accessing doesn't allow static scraping , you need to use advance scraping using selenium like this..

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.yellowpages.com.au/find/boat-yacht-sales/melbourne-vic"

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="{location}/chromedriver")
driver.get(url)
content_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='search-results 
listing-group']")
content_html = content_element[0].get_attribute("innerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(content_html, "html.parser")
print soup
```

since the class name contains space , so you need to use something like xpath or id to fetch the data.
For more info on advance scraping read this one:
https://medium.com/dualcores-studio/advanced-web-scraping-in-python-d19dfccba235